# C# UnityEvents - Override

Tags: c#, inheritance, events, unity-game-engine, extends

I had been searching so much to solve my problem but I found nothing.

So, what is my problem?
I have a class that extends from UnityEvent and it has 2 virtual methods and it has public identifier in another file that should call those methods. But when I put my script in inspector nothing happens (except root virtual methods).

The class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Collections;

namespace Namespace {
    [System.Serializable]
    public class SomeClass : UnityEvent {
        public virtual void OnSomething(GameObject objectSender, GameObject objectAction) {

        }
        public virtual void OnSomethingElse(GameObject objectSender, GameObject objectAction) {
        }
    }
}
```

I overrided those methods in a file and but in variable "script" shown below but they are not overrided. 
And using of SomeClass:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Collections;

namespace Namespace {
    public class ActionListener : MonoBehaviour {
        public SomeClass script;

        // When I lose last hope
        // private void Start() {
        //  script.Invoke();
        //}
        public void OnHover(GameObject sender, GameObject action) {
            script.OnHoverListener(sender, action);
        }
        public void OnClick(GameObject sender, GameObject action) {
            script.OnClickListener(sender, action);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: script.OnHoverListener(args) is OnSomething(args). The same is applied to  OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using MonoBehaviour instead UnityEvent.

And not it looks like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Collections;

namespace Namespace {
    public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {
        public virtual void OnSomething(GameObject objectSender, GameObject objectAction) {

        }
        public virtual void OnSomethingElse(GameObject objectSender, GameObject objectAction) {
        }
    }
}
```

And in use

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Collections;

namespace Namespace {
    public class ActionListener : MonoBehaviour {
        public SomeClass script;

        public void OnHover(GameObject sender, GameObject action) {
            script.OnSomething(sender, action);
        }
        public void OnClick(GameObject sender, GameObject action) {
            script.OnSomethingElse(sender, action);
        }
    }
}
```